# finding limit of a series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

So I have a series like so:

> $$a_n = \frac{1+ (-1)^n}{2^n + 24}$$

I managed to get to:

$$n < \log_2 \left(\frac{2}{\epsilon} - 24\right)$$

basically i need to find an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ and show that for any $n$ that is bigger than $N$ the expression works..

thank you! (btw i don't know how to use latex code to show the accurate symbols so if you're not sure on what i wrote i'll upload a photo)

Comment: I think you may have meant "sequence" and not "series", didn't you?

Comment: What "expression" works?

Comment: uhmm.. in my language we call it a series, i may have been wrong.

Comment: @DonAntonio i need to find an N number which is a natural number, that for any n that is also a natural number that is bigger than N, that the last line i wrote is correct. English is not my first lang so i apologise if im making it hard to understand

Comment: I really find it hard to understand what you mean: there is not symbol $\;\sum\;$ in your post and thus I suppose you mean **a sequence**. Now, the sequence you wrote converges to zero and the series with the general temr $\;a_n\;$ also converges. You wrote that you "managed to get to"...but why?! What is it that you need to find out or to prove?!

Comment: @DarkLeader *Hint:* Factor out $2^n$ and apply basic limit laws.

Comment: @DonAntonio I need to find the limit of the sequence i wrote above. in order to do that, i was told to "guess" what the limit is and show that |an - L| < epsilon where L is the limit and epsilon is greater than 0. if you work it out.. you will reach 2 cases, if n % 2 == 0 or n % 2 == 1 so for the last case the sequence converges to 0 but for the first case, if n % 2 == 0 im having issues finding a 'n' number that is a natural number so that for a specific N which is also a natural number, that sequence will always converge to 0.

Comment: @DonAntonio basically it's impossible because that for the last expression to be work epsilon must be less than 0 but according to the definition i was given, always assume epsilon is greater than 0. do you understand my problem now?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Take two subsequences, $(e_n)_{n=0}^\infty = (a_{2n})_{n = 0}^\infty$ and $O = (a_{2n+1})_{n = 0}^\infty$. Notice that all terms of $O$ are zero, so it trivially converges to zero. As for $E$, we have
$$
e_n = a_{2n} = \frac{2}{2^{2n} + 24} = \frac{1}{\frac12 \cdot 4^n + 12},
$$
and it should not be a problem to show that $e_n \to 0$ as well, so both $E$ and $O$ partition the original sequence and converge to the same value, so the original sequence would as well...

Comment: is this the "The sandwich rule" ? if so i can't use it. i must use |an - L| < epsilon

Answer (score 0):

Note that we have $$\left|\frac{1+(-1)^n}{2^n+24}\right|\le \frac{2}{2^n}$$